# Show 404 Not found for Query strings with pattern site.com/?xyz

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress site issue with spam in google indexed in format site.com/?xyz, site.com/?etc;
I searched for showing 404 Not found for these query strings with this code in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php? [L,R=404]
```

The problem is that this code turns every query string in URL to 404 not found no matter it locates on site.com/?blabla or site.com/page1/?blablabla; what i want is that 404 Not found for just site.com/? strings, and no other query string should be effected. Please help to modify the code. With the above code wordpress theme, plugins and ads loading are affected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(\/)?$ /404.php? [L,R=404]
```

Comment: That did not work, spam URLs are: site.com/?hsgadgagsdg ; site.com/?sbwydbwehj ; site.com/?jsdhhsbdjhsbd; and with the above code only site.com/? is captured and transferred to 404. There could be any string after "site.com/?" any help?

Comment: Not working, site.com/?hvjbjhbjjh string shows to home page

Comment: Thanks for the help, the previous code worked well on simple http site, not for its https:// variant, I mean that when URL is http://example.com/?gsdghsdv; that lands to 404 Not found, but when URL is https://example.com/?gsdghsdv, then the page is loaded with home page contents with the URL "https://example.com/?gsdghsdv"; I also want it to land to 404 Not found.